# How to copy a part of text, and populate inputs with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What is the best way to import data with Jquery or PHP.

I need read textarea, and identify blocks like this

name: this is name, age:this is age 
I need to get only parts between name: I NEED GET THIS age:

I dont have any idea how, and what I need use for make this. So I need one idea how i can begin?

The jquery selector, not important, becouse i can use any think like on change, or button click function, this is indiferent...

```
<textarea id='import'>
this is pasted text...
name: this is name 
age: this is age
other: have but i dont need
other2: have but i dont need
city: this is city
obs: this is obs </textarea>
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="age">
<input type="text" id="city">
<input type="text" id="obs">
<button>Import</button>
```

Comment: What then do you want to do with your data, once formatted?

Comment: @grenoult i send it a multiples inputs values

Comment: *"with Jquery or PHP"* - Huh? These aren't comparable options. Are you trying to do this client-side or after the data is submitted to the server? Do the "fields" in the textarea end with newline characters? You could extract the relevant bits with regular expression matching, but if you're dealing with user-pasted data how can you be sure there won't be several "name" fields, or none?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm understand you... but really, its not a problem, because i need one way for specific blocks search in the text and get this values for  after use. with php or js not important in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this javascript code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("import");

input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  var content = input.value;
  
  content.replace(/(\S+): ?(.+)/g, function(m, id, value) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) element.value = value;
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="import"></textarea>
<br>name: <input type="text" id="name">
<br>age: <input type="text" id="age">
<br>city: <input type="text" id="city">
<br>obs: <input type="text" id="obs">
```

You can see the regex in [action here.](https://regex101.com/r/zT2cT7/1)

Comment: I think it will work. I'll try. @Guedes 
This site is amazing, you save my life!!! :) 
Thank you so mutch.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: you have ideia, how i can use data-atribute-name instead input id?

Comment: If jQuery is an option, you can use `$('[data-attribute-name="something"]')`... if you have any troubles, feel free to ask a new question. By now I'm going to sleep, it's midnight here ;)

Comment: Thank you! =) Good Night